How to figure out what permissions I need from the helm template?
I am trying to install Sentry using helm chart - https://github.com/sentry-kubernetes/charts/tree/develop/charts/sentry
I get this error -
[]$ helm install sentry sentry/sentry -f values.yaml
coalesce.go:175: warning: skipped value for kafka.config: Not a table.
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: could not get information about the resource NetworkPolicy "sentry-kafka" in namespace "gopikab": networkpolicies.networking.k8s.io "sentry-kafka" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:gopikab" cannot get resource "networkpolicies" in API group "networking.k8s.io" in the namespace "gopikab"

I template the chart and get the output. Based on helm template, how do I figure out what permissions I need and to what roles and api groups.
When I template the chart - these are the roles and rolebindings mentioned -

# Source: sentry/charts/rabbitmq/templates/role.yaml
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: sentry-rabbitmq-endpoint-reader
  namespace: "gopikab"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: rabbitmq
    helm.sh/chart: rabbitmq-11.16.2
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: sentry
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "3.11.18"
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["endpoints"]
    verbs: ["get"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["events"]
    verbs: ["create"]
---
# Source: sentry/charts/rabbitmq/templates/rolebinding.yaml
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: sentry-rabbitmq-endpoint-reader
  namespace: "gopikab"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: rabbitmq
    helm.sh/chart: rabbitmq-11.16.2
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: sentry
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "3.11.18"
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: sentry-rabbitmq
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: sentry-rabbitmq-endpoint-reader
---



If you run helm template, you can get the listing of Kubernetes manifests the chart wants to install, and from there you can find out what kinds of objects are included in the chart.
helm template sentry/sentry -f values.yaml | egrep 'apiVersion|kind'

For each pair of API group and object kind, you (the entity actually running helm) need create, get, list, update, and delete permissions in your effective Role(s); any Role(s) embedded in the chart won't be considered.

Thank you.
I provided permissions to access the Network Policy
I had to make a new ClusterRole.

Maybe you just need access to view Network Policy.
